# How to use d3js force layout to generate the default hierarchical layout generated by graphviz dot

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graphviz

Instead of the sample spring layout shown in the examples
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045
I would like to have d3js print something like:
http://www.graphviz.org/content/profile

I am new to javascript or any kind of web programming. A simple code sample which generates a graph with three nodes and two connections to print like

A
|
B
|
C

would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Force direction, then your 'tree-like' structure will definitely break.
You+re are better of with augmenting a Tree if what you need is a Directed Acyclic Graph.

Check the examples for Tree
http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html

and circle cluster:
http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/cluster.html

You hav ethe code below the graphs.

Comment: Thanks, this works. However I needed something that will print things from top to bottom. I will probably figure that out and maybe post a snippet when I am done.

Comment: Here you have a top-down tree: [link](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/999346/b5b8d7a83b564c68959c137814cf17cf65b254ed)